# Create random tree from array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree

I'm at a dead end and I need your help. I have array in JavaScript with random strings and the task is to make shuffled tree where every parent has 3 children, these 3 children have 9 children (3 children per every upper child). For example, I have an array:

```
const x = [
  'apple', 'bus', 'banana', 'pen', 'pencil', 'earth', 'planet', 'flat', 
  'house', 'dream', 'train', 'space', 'drink', 'cola'
];
```

And code should generate something like this:

```
[
  {
    parent: 'apple',
    children: [
      {
        parent: 'pen',
        children: [
          {
            parent: 'drink',
            children: []
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        parent: 'planet',
        children: []
      },
      {
        parent: 'dream',
        children: []
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    parent: 'bus',
    children: [
      {
        parent: 'pencil',
        children: [
          {
            parent: 'cola',
            children: []
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        parent: 'flat',
        children: []
      },
      {
        parent: 'train',
        children: []
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    parent: 'banana',
    children: [
      {
        parent: 'earth',
        children: []
      },
      {
        parent: 'house',
        children: []
      },
      {
        parent: 'space',
        children: []
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

So, deeper level should not be filled until last level in ALL PARENTS is not filled. Please, help!

I tried to create some recursive function, but it was too large and not really automated, so I think there are better and light way to make this, and I need some experts help...

Comment: Please share your effort as a text-based [mcve]. Asking us to create the program from scratch isn't kind.

Comment: *"I need some experts help"*: we can help if you provide your code, and pinpoint exactly where it goes wrong. What is the "dead end" you speak of? An error? An infinite loop? Wrong output? Please focus your question on the *problem* you encountered with *your* code.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you.
Well actually this is something like an algorithm test.
We need to generate a random tree and the structure should be such that one parent should have 3 children and deeper levels should not be filled until all parents at the last level are not filled.

So here I'm going to generate a random  tree using recursive function. Top level should have 3 parents, and next level 9. so every level requires `3^level` nodes.

Let's say that we have 27 nodes. I'll call each node as 1, 2, 3, ... 27

- top level: 1, 2, 3

  - Parent 1 could have 4, 5, 6
  - Parent 2 could have 7, 8, 9
  - Parent 3 could have 10, 11, 12
- next level: 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12

  - Parent 4 could have 13, 14, 15
  - Parent 5 could have 16, 17, 18
  - Parent 6 could have 19, 20, 21
  - ...

In this kind of way we can recursively get the tree that satisfies the condition.

Try this.

```js
const x = [
  'apple', 'bus', 'banana', 'pen', 'pencil', 'earth', 'planet', 'flat', 
  'house', 'dream', 'train', 'space', 'drink', 'cola'
];

function generateTree(level, startIndex, count) {
  const tempIndex = 3 * (startIndex + 1)
  if (x.length >= count) {
    const children = x.slice(tempIndex, tempIndex + 3).map((item, index) => {
      return {
        parent: item,
        children: generateTree(
          level + 1,
          tempIndex + index,
          count + Math.pow(3, level)
        ),
      }
    })
    return children
  } else {
    return []
  }
}

console.log(generateTree(1, -1, 0))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).